# fullPage.js onLeave event triggers

Tags: jquery, css, fullpage.js

I am attempting to trigger two CSS events when switching sections on a fullPage.js app.  Please see a fiddle of where I'm currently at here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pingo_/67oe1jvn/2/

I would like to do the following two things:

- Change the class of the fa-stack icons to attributes under hover when I leave the page (currently the color is only changing on click/hover, but I would like it to change if the use just scrolls)
- Change the color of the navigation nodes to #ffffff when the background color is #004e7b (currently cannot see the nodes in sections 2 and 4)

What is the best way to achieve this? I have some code at the bottom of the javascript breakout that attempts to trigger a message when I leave section one. This actually messes up the scrolling completely and skips all the way to the last section:

```
var fromSection1 = false;
$('#fullpage').fullpage({       
  onLeave: function(index, direction){
     var leavingSection = $(this);
    //after leaving section 2
    if(index == 1 && direction =='down'){
      alert("Going to section 2!");
    }else{
      fromSection1 = false;
    }
  }
});
```

And would I do something similar to trigger a change of class for the fa-nav sections?  I have not written anything in the css, bc I am not sure if it should be done there, in the javascript, or in both.  I have not injected class attributes before and am having a lot of difficulty with these two.  Please advise the best approach and see if you are able to help. Thanks !!

Comment: Was working off of this: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in an answer provided one year ago... Now the `onLeave` event has 3 parameters intead of two as you can see [here in the documentation.](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction)

> onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){

Regarding your questions, to change a class you need javascript. But maybe that's not what you need.

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

Remember fullPage.js adds the class `active` to the active section, and in the `body` element it adds the class `fp-viewing-xxx` where xxx is the `anchor` name of the current section or its index if no anchors are provided.

This way you can play with css:

```
#demo{
    color: red;
} 

/* applied only on the section with the anchor `firstpage` */     
body.fp-viewing-firstpage #demo{
    color: blue;
}
```