# fullpage.js animation with onLeave and afterLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fullpage.js

i'm using fullpage.js and i'd like to animate 2 images as soon as i get to the second section. looks like i can't make it work with css only, so i picked up some js code from the documentation. check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/67oe1jvn/9/

the thing is: if i scroll down to the second section, the 2 images get animated and fade in from left and right sides. BUT if i change section, nothing happens... now i want the to "disappear" as soon as i leave the second section.

i used afterLoad and onLoad as said in the documentation, like this:

```
$.fn.fullpage({

afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);
        if(index == 1){
            $('#slidetext1 #rock').animate({right:"0px"});
            $('#slidetext1 #deer').animate({left:"0px"});
        }
    },
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var leavingSection = $(this);
        if(index == 2 && direction =='up'){
            $('#slidetext1 #rock').animate({right:"-271px"});
            $('#slidetext1 #deer').animate({left:"-271px"});

      } else if(index == 2 && direction == 'down'){
            /* DO SOMETHING */
        }
}
});
```

i'm new with this plugins so would be cool if someone helps me :)

also i saw this guy posting a similar question that maybe can help clarifying what i need:  [fullPage.js onLeave event triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461952/fullpage-js-onleave-event-triggers) .

Comment: EDIT: i hosted the site on a free domain here: http://yolorekt.co.nf/
if you scroll down to the second section you will see 2 images showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

- If you post a jsfiddle, make sure it works... because it doesn't at all.
- You are initializing fullPage.js twice in your site. Inside `myjs.js` and outside it..
- You can create animations with just css if you want. Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

If you want the images to dissappear again you'll have to tell fullPage.js to do it. It won't magically happen.
Just use the `onLeave` again and say something like "whenever the next slide is not section 2, then hide my images".

```
if(nextIndex != 2){
   //hide images
}
```